# Trouble opening an Excel file with preview

Tags: macos, preview, quicklook

I maintain a library that reads and writes Microsoft Excel files. Due to some recent changes neither Preview, Quicklook or Numbers can open the file. Is there are any way to get debug information from any of these (or the underlying libraries)?

I'm specifically looking for command like flags such as -d 4 which will provide more information as to why the Preview / Quicklook / Numbers can't open the file. ie. some kind of informative error message such as "can't parse the XML".

Feedback from the OOXML Working Group about relative references:

> What do you mean by a relative reference?  In RFC 3986, a relative
>   reference is either an absolute-path reference (e.g., /foo/bar) or a
>   relative-path reference (e.g., foo/bar).  OPC already allows both.

So this is a bug in the Apple software stack. I'll update the bug report accordingly.

Comment: You really need to provide more details. What type of library do you maintain? What type of changes occurred recently? What versions of macOS and Numbers are we talking about? Anything else that may be relevant?

Comment: Please attach one of your files to a new bug on http://bugreport.apple.com and an helpful Apple engineer will look at your file and either tell you what's wrong with it or fix it :-)

Comment: And send us the radar number here (or at least attach the file)

Comment: @ThomasDeniau "an (sic) helpful Apple engineer will look at your file...", that's very funny!  Perhaps OP doesn't have a few years for someone at Apple to look at his bug report, how else can he get the debug info he's looking for?

Comment: there's no debug info, this is why I'm asking for the file

Comment: A bug for the library has been filed. https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/677/ I'm not at all hopeful that anyone at Apple will pull the finger out to look at this.

Comment: Nobody will take a look if you don't file a radar :-)

Comment: I'm asking for information about possible command line flags.

Comment: It isn't really clear what your question is here and what kind of answer you are seeking. The text indicates some issues with previewing Excel files, the filed bug indicates an issue with a third-party tool and your latest comment indicates that you are looking for some command line tool. Can you please edit your question to describe the problem and your need better?

Comment: I can't answer the question because it has been marked as unclear, but I've posted an explanation of your issue on the openpyxl bug you've posted above. You're using an absolute path for some of the relationships in your Excel file and this is invalid according to the spec. Make the paths relative like Excel does and it works with Quick Look, Preview and Numbers. See, sometimes there are helpful Apple engineers....

Comment: @ThomasDeniau thanks for taking the time to look at the problem in more detail. I'll probably file a bug with the OOXML working group to get the guidance on packaging changed (there is no good reason for it and it is **not* reflected in the schema). I'll also file a bug with Apple to see if the relevant team can make the necessary change. I've filed bugs with Apple in the past only for them to sink without trace and personally sat on a broken system for several months last year because, well, App Store. Apple has many talented and dedicated engineers.

Comment: Filed by as #28562033. Unfortunately it does not seem that Apple provides public URLs for bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The general manner to get at logs on macOS (and OS X in the past) is to open the Console app. It shows the common application and system logging framework and allows you to search across all sources and databases that store logs.

If you are unix based - much of this logging is documented in manual pages and at [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/asl.3.html).

Many third party packages have documentation - like [python](http://pythonhosted.org/asl/) to interact with and document logging.

Your specific needs will depend on the exact version and build of the OS and the preview app, but start with Console and consider asking a follow on question once you have specifics.

Quicklook is going to be a much harder nut to crack, since you need to know about spotlight importer details, less direct databases and layers of indirection and storage. Spotlight debugging is more of a book than an answer here as a side question.

I'd also skip excel - since that's not really an Apple product - focus on getting your file to work in Preview and you'll likely be good to go.

Comment: I've got no problem reading the console logs. It's just that relevant messages aren't helpful. This is why I was looking for debug options.